# Get pre-defined colors into table in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I'm doing some plots in TikZ via matlab2tikz, which gave me the following output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
colormap/jet,
scale only axis,
xmin=7,
xmax=9.5,
xlabel={(hh0)},
ymin=11.7,
ymax=12.7,
ylabel={(00l)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit,scatter/use mapped color={mark=*,mark options={},draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color}] plot table[row sep=crcr,meta index=2]{%
7.38517703285077    11.8600971333007    1\\
7.96222790369133    11.9099275551383    2\\
8.49288094528219    11.9557513572467    3\\
8.9868007534447 11.998403112297 4\\
9.45070037936319    12.0384625164465    5\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine. I would, however, like to be able to use a predefined color, such as

```
\colorlet{color1}{SkyBlue}
```

for the color of the first scatter point, and then some color2 for the second, and so forth. Right now, the third column in the table defines the color of the points with respect to the jet colorscheme.

How do I go about this? I've tried creating a class for each of the five data types (such that 1 -> [a]), and just writing the name of the color in place of the color integers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried creating a class for each of the five data types (such that
>   1 -> [a]), and just writing the name of the color in place of the
>   color integers.

Did you do like this?

```
scatter/classes={
1={mark=*,mark options={},blue},%
2={mark=*,mark options={},red},%
3={mark=*,mark options={},color1},%      color1 is defined as you did.
4={mark=*,mark options={},green},%
5={mark=*,mark options={},olive}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{color1}{SkyBlue}      %%<--- define colors

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=7,
xmax=9.5,
xlabel={(hh0)},
ymin=11.7,
ymax=12.7,
ylabel={(00l)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit,
scatter/classes={
1={mark=*,mark options={},blue},%
2={mark=*,mark options={},red},%
3={mark=*,mark options={},color1},%
4={mark=*,mark options={},green},%
5={mark=*,mark options={},olive}
},] plot table[row sep=crcr,meta index=2]{%
7.38517703285077    11.8600971333007    1\\
7.96222790369133    11.9099275551383    2\\
8.49288094528219    11.9557513572467    3\\
8.9868007534447 11.998403112297 4\\
9.45070037936319    12.0384625164465    5\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, almost like that. I think my problem was in not removing some of the scatter/use mapped color settings, else it looked very much like this. Should have thought of this myself. Thank you very much!